# Using objects to simplify code in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to make code easy to read.
There are too duplicated methods like this.

```
var svg = d3.append('svg').attr(...).attr('...').attr('...').style(...).style(...);
```

This is a bit difficult to read so I want to simplify code.

```
var svg = d3.append('svg').attr({'class','test_class'},{'x','x_value'}).style({'fill','value'},{...});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**D3 version 3.x**

You can do that using D3 v3.x. Check the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg");

var data = [10, 5, 15, 20, 12, 8, 17];

var circles = svg.selectAll(".circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle");

circles.attr({
    cx: function (d,i) { return 10 + i*40; },
    cy: 50,
    r:  function (d) { return d; },
    fill: "teal"
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**D3 version 4.x**

However, this will not work in the new D3 v4.x. For passing objects like that, you'll need the [`selection-multi`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi):

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Besides that, have in mind that you'll have to change:

- `attr` must be `attrs`
- `style` must be `styles`

Check the demo using v4.x:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg");

var data = [10, 5, 15, 20, 12, 8, 17];

var circles = svg.selectAll(".circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle");

circles.attrs({
    cx: function (d,i) { return 10 + i*40; },
    cy: 50,
    r:  function (d) { return d; },
    fill: "teal"
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
```

PS: your example of simplified code (the second one) is not a valid object (because the key/value pair is separated by comma instead of colon) or a valid array (because there is no square bracket). Thus, it should be:

```
.attr({'class': 'test_class', 'x': 'x_value'})
```

Comment: Seems like it's not supported in v4, no?